# Mostrar dados Mysql dentro do JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um arquivo chamado somar.js onde contém alguns comandos JQuery, entre eles a soma dos pacotes * valor do câmbio diário, só que esses valores vem do banco de dados. Para evitar com que o administrador cadastre no sistema e manualmente nesse arquivo, gostaria de saber se é possível trazer resultados do mysql dentro do JQuery ou inserir comandos PHP em arquivos js. Veja abaixo o trecho que preciso dessa solução:

```
var taxaCambio = 4.20; // Nessa linha

        var totalGeralSomar = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4;
        var totalCambio = totalGeralSomar * taxaCambio;
        if(totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2) == "NaN" || totalCambio.toFixed(2) == "NaN"){
            document.getElementById("totalGeral").innerHTML = "R$ 0.00";
            document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "USD 0.00";
        }else{

            Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
                var n = this, 
                    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
                    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
                    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
                    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
                    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
                    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
                   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
                 };

             document.getElementById("totalGeral").innerHTML = "R$ " +(totalCambio).formatMoney(2, ',', '.');;
            document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "USD " +totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2);
        }
```

Comment: Dentro de um arquivo *.js, não é possivel colocar comandos php. Se o script estiver no html e não em um arquivo .js é possivel. No seu caso seria interessante criar uma variavel javascript global e carregar o valor do banco nela.

Comment: Oi Jhonatan, mas como eu faria para carregar o valor do banco? Sou um pouco leigo em JQuery.

Comment: Bom dentro do arquivo js sem chance. Você já tem a conexão do banco e a variavel php com o valor? Se sim posto a solução que pensei para vc

Comment: Oi Jhonatan, tenho sim. O sistema foi desenvolvido em PHP/Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, veja se te ajuda a solução proposta.

Solução 1 ( Colocar o javascript na sua pagina sem ser em um arquivo externo ):

Remova a inclusão do arquivo js da sua pagina e coloque o código abaixo entre `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

```js
    var taxaCambio = <?=$suaVariavelCambio;?>; // Substituir por sua variavel PHP
    var totalGeralSomar = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4;
    var totalCambio = totalGeralSomar * taxaCambio;
    if(totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2) == "NaN" || totalCambio.toFixed(2) == "NaN"){
        document.getElementById("totalGeral").innerHTML = "R$ 0.00";
        document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "USD 0.00";
    }else{

        Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
            var n = this, 
                c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
                d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
                t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
                s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
                i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
                j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
               return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
             };

         document.getElementById("totalGeral").innerHTML = "R$ " +(totalCambio).formatMoney(2, ',', '.');;
        document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "USD " +totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Solução 2 ( Definir uma global js que recebe o valor do php e depois pega-la no arquivo ):

Adicione o código abaixo entre as tags `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

`var Globais = {}; // Definir a global
Globais.taxaCambio = <?=$suaVariavelCambio;?>;`

Então dentro do seu arquivo JS mude para:

```js
    var taxaCambio = Globais.taxaCambio; // Substituir por sua variavel PHP
    var totalGeralSomar = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4;
    var totalCambio = totalGeralSomar * taxaCambio;
    if(totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2) == "NaN" || totalCambio.toFixed(2) == "NaN"){
        document.getElementById("totalGeral").innerHTML = "R$ 0.00";
        document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "USD 0.00";
    }else{

        Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
            var n = this, 
                c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
                d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
                t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
                s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
                i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
                j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
               return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
             };

         document.getElementById("totalGeral").innerHTML = "R$ " +(totalCambio).formatMoney(2, ',', '.');;
        document.getElementById("subTotal").innerHTML = "USD " +totalGeralSomar.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Apenas atente para incluir o *.js abaixo da definição da global ou use o `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @Romario Pires a sugestão proposta é irrelevante, tendo em vista que `<?=$variavel;?>` funciona da mesma forma que `<?php echo $variavel;?>`

Comment: Olá Jhonatan, na verdade eu havia pensado em colocar dessa forma, porém o código js é grande e acho que não seria legal colocar diretamente na página. Não existe nenhum plugin JQuery que faça isso?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos inclui uma outra solução na resposta. Veja se consegue entender e se funciona.

Comment: Bingo Jhonatan na segunda solução. Muito obrigado e desde já quero lhe desejar um Feliz 2016, com muita prosperidade, saúde e paz. Abraço.

Comment: Feliz 2016 pra você tambem mano